# interpolate to larger 1D array using python

Tags: python, arrays, signal-processing, interpolation, wavelet

I have five 1D array with multiple length.I want all the arrays to have the same length as `cD1`. I want to apply interpolation on the arrays to have the same length. 
 I've attempted to use `linear_interp = interp1d(cD5, cD1)` , but it doesn't work properly. Any help is appreciated!

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
coeffs = wavedec(data, 'sym5', level=5)
cA5,cD5,cD4,cD3,cD2,cD1=coeffs
cD5.shape #(248,)
cD4.shape #(488,)
cD3.shape #(967,)
cD2.shape #(1926,)
cD1.shape #(3844,)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell you are missing an `x` coordinate.

Try to add a common `x` coordinate for your arrays:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

common_length_data = []
common_x = np.linspace(0, 1, len(cD1))
for c in [cA5,cD5,cD4,cD3,cD2,cD1]:
    x = np.linspace(0, 1, len(c))
    f = interp1d(x, c)
    common_length_data.append(f(common_x))
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I got this error `ValueError: x and y arrays must be equal in length along interpolation axis`

Comment: I made some edits since my first answer. Do you still get the error?

Comment: nope,thanks a lot  for the solution. I want to ask about 0 and 1 in `linspace` what  they indicate?? , then now `common_length_data` a list contain all the arrays having the same length ??

Comment: `0` and `1` in `linspace` are the first and final value of the x coordinate (the particular values should not matter - you could put any other numbers). And yes, `common_length_data` is the list that contains the requested arrays.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution.